# Data disappears from view with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to display a list of Posts and add a checkbox with a `Publish` button to publish multiple Posts at a time. I can display the list of Posts just fine, but when I try to wrap the list in a `form_tag`, based on [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) rails cast, it is not displaying any of my Posts.

Here's my view:

```
        <table id="pending-posts" class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Created at</th>
              <th>User</th>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Expiration</th>
              <th>Published</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <% form_tag toggle_selected_publish_posts_path, :method => :put do %>
                <% @posts_inactive.each do |post| %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= check_box_tag "post_ids[]", post.id %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></td>
                    <td><%= post.created_at.to_s(:short) %></td>
                    <td><%= post.user.email %></td>
                    <td><%= post.user.email %></td>
                    <td><%= post.state.name %></td>
                    <td><%= post.city.name %></td>
                    <td><%= post.expire_date.to_s(:short) %></td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <div class="dark" style="float:left;">
                              <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post), :class => 'btn btn-mini dark' %> &nbsp;
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:left;">
                              <%= button_to 'Delete', post_path(post), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dark" style="float:left;">
                                 &nbsp; <%= link_to publish_link_text(post), 
                                            toggle_publish_post_path(post), 
                                            :class => 'btn btn-mini dark' %>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear:both;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>   
              <%= submit_tag "Publish Selected" %>
            <% end %>

          </tbody>
        </table>
```

I followed the example on the rails cast and modeled my view, routes, and controller exactly as shown, but I'm still not getting anything.

When I remove the form code lines, the data is display so I assume the issue is something to do with my form.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for awhile and I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
<% form_tag toggle_selected_publish_posts_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Should be

```
<%= form_tag toggle_selected_publish_posts_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Comment: That got my data back... THANKS! But the submit button isn't doing anything... On to other problems!